# python error "non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe9' " when trying to compile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this small code to pop up a windows message:

```
#-*- coding:Utf-8 -*-
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, u"This file is not supported by your current version of Windows", u"Windows Error Message",
```

It works well , but when I try to compile it with "pyinstaller errormessage.py", I get this error :

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe9' in file C:\Users\Thérèse\AppDat
a\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but
 no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I went to the python.org but I dont really understand what is the fix, please not that I am a beginner in python

Comment: `'\xe9'` is an `é` in latin-1, and invalid in utf-8.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille there is no "é" in my code though

Comment: but I have an "é" in my directery ("C:\Users\Thérèse\Documents\PYTOEXEICON")  do you think that could be the source of the problem ?

Comment: Since that path encoded in `latin-1` is `b'C:\\Users\\Th\xe9r\xe8se\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\pyinstaller-script.py'`, that looks quite likely.  Not sure how to declare encoding for pyinstaller, but perhaps placing the files elsewhere might be the quickest way around it.

Comment: I changer my user name and im reinstalling python. should work... I hope

Comment: bad idea... gotta modify all the paths in regedit